# На странице добавления способов входа не переведён текст валидатора

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, способы-входа

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм.. Это сообщение браузера - переключи интерфейс на русский.

Comment: @Qwertiy впервые такое сообщение вижу, если честно. Думал, это валидатор самого SO D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это встроенное в браузер сообщение - переключи его интерфейс на русский.

```html
<form><input type=email required autofocus> <input type=submit></form>
```

[image: скриншот]